# Force of Jet from Air Compressor

Tags: compressed-air, compressors

I want to use a compressor to create a jet of air. At discharge from compressor how much CFM (Cubic Feet per Minute) are enough to create a force that can turn a heavy object (say 40 kg) at 3 rev per sec placed in front of air jet.

Just looking for a relationship between CFM and Jet Force.

Thanks.

Comment: This may help : https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/how-to-calculate-pressure-and-flow-rate-of-an-air-jet.669931/

Comment: Impossible to answer without a lot more information. As an example, when doing vibration testing on jet engines it is useful to keep the rotors turning slowly so the bearings don't "stick" in one position. You can turn those rotors, weighing half a ton or more, at about 1 RPM simply by pointing a 10-dollar desk fan at the front of the engine to blow a bit of air through it. But the OP's system is probably not so accurately balanced and free-running as that!

Comment: And at the opposite extreme, the leaves of a "paper plate" tree (aka Sea Grape) completely resist being shifted by even the biggest leaf blowers if they are lying on a flattish surface.This property makes them a fantastic dune and beach stabilizer.

Comment: My point was purely related with Fluid Dynamics point where Volume Flow Rate can give force because of momentum change...

Comment: This is a classic Newton’s Third Law example question - what’s the mass flow rate of air? What’s its velocity and momentum? If it comes to a stop, how much has it imparted?